# Slow profiling with Eclipse TPTP

Tags: eclipse, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I've developing an application in Eclipse 3.6 and am trying to get some simple execution profiling statistics with TPTP (basically just the execution time analysis).

However, the profiling is running so slowing that it's barely possible to get a successful run, Eclipse sometimes crashes with OutOfMemoryErrors and I highly doubt that any of the execution time statistics are anything close to what I normally get. I guess it's running about 100th of normal speed, using 100% of a CPU.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this and how I could fix it?

System is Core i7 980 running Windows 7 64-bit, JVM is Sun JDK 1.6.20 in case that is relevant

Comment: Other strange point: the status bar indicates the total number of "bytes processed" (around 170,000,000), however the "bytes/second" keeps falling, suggesting that is is getting slower and slower.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with [**this `eclipse.ini` file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) for some optimization and hopefully and better runtime experience?.

Note: keep the Java1.6u20, or make sure ti use the 1.6u21 build 7 (not build 6).
That way, you will ensure the `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` parameter (that you should set to an high value in order to facilitate your session) will be correctly recognized.

Comment: Thanks! The memory settings here seem to have helped enormously. Why can'y they have these as the defaults :-) It's still a bit slow, but has definitely fixed the crashes and grinding to a halt

Answer (score 0):

please try this

following is the instructions to switch built in profiling database with newer version

1. close your eclipse ide
2. browse to your-workspace-folder/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2
3. copy all files under this folder to another location as a backup
4. and delete all files with .db extension
5. download latest version of H2 database for All Platforms zip from this [link](http://h2database.com/html/main.html)
6. goto your-eclipse-folder\plugins\ and find the file something like org.h2_1.1.117.v201105142352.jar and copy it to some place as a backup
7. extract the zip file downloaded on step 5
8. you will find the file h2-1.3.170.jar under h2\bin\ folder
9. rename h2-1.3.170.jar to the file name from the step 6 which is org.h2_1.1.117.v201105142352.jar
10. after this you can put the file renamed in step 9 into the folder your-eclipse-folder\plugins\
11. you can try to start your eclipse

please let me know if this makes your eclipse run faster